# Special relativity book which describes concepts using linear algebra notions

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, inertial-frames, linear-algebra

It seems so every idea of special relativity can be formulated quite nicely in Linear algebra notions such as the inner product matrix and change of basis matrices. However, I can't find a single book which discusses it through the context of Linear algebra.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into "Einstein in Matrix Form: Exact Derivation of the Theory of Special and General Relativity without Tensors".

Answer (score 3):

Here are two suggestions written by relativists with an emphasis on the spacetime-geometric viewpoint that are appropriate for physics undergraduates.

- Geroch's "Mathematical Physics" (1985, ISBN 978-0226288628) book has two chapters:
  Ch 15 "Example: Minkowski Vector Space" and Ch 16 "Example: The Lorentz Group". The emphasis is on representing the physics in the mathematics. The linear algebraic operations use linearity and dot-products.
  Since the presentation is concise, I think that this reference requires some mathematical sophistication from the reader.


  There isn't much here on Lorentz Transformations as "matrices"
  since his approach is coordinate-free.
  At the end of Ch 15, Geroch writes:
  *"2. One takes care at the beginning to be sure that "the mathematics is
  appropriate for the physics," that is, that everything in the mathematics has
  physical meaning and that all of the physics one wishes to talk about is
  describable in terms of the mathematics. In particular, one tries to avoid
  structural features (e.g., a basis for the vector space) which have no physical
  significance."*
- Woodhouse, "Special Relativity" (1992, ISBN 3540550496) might be a good balance of physics, spacetime-geometric reasoning, and linear-algebraic presentations with dot-products and with matrices. In the preface, he writes *"The emphasis is on the use of coordinate-free and tensorial methods: I tried
  to avoid the traditional arguments based on the standard Lorentz transformation, and to encourage students to look at problems from a four-dimensional point of view."*